# TypeError: '...' has type str, but expected one of: bytes

Tags: python, tensorflow, tensorflow2.0, object-detection, object-detection-api

I'm trying to get basic Tensorflow bounding box object detection working on Open Images Dataset (v6)...

```
  File "/home/work/models/research/object_detection/dataset_tools/create_oid_tf_record.py", line 115, in main
    tf_example = oid_tfrecord_creation.tf_example_from_annotations_data_frame(
  File "/root/anaconda3/lib/python3.8/site-packages/object_detection/dataset_tools/oid_tfrecord_creation.py", line 71, in tf_example_from_annotations_data_frame
    dataset_util.bytes_feature('{}.jpg'.format(image_id)),
  File "/root/anaconda3/lib/python3.8/site-packages/object_detection/utils/dataset_util.py", line 33, in bytes_feature
    return tf.train.Feature(bytes_list=tf.train.BytesList(value=[value]))
TypeError: '000411001ff7dd4f.jpg' has type str, but expected one of: bytes
```

The relevant code seems to be here:

```
def bytes_feature(value):
    return tf.train.Feature(bytes_list=tf.train.BytesList(value=[value]))
```

I thought maybe `value=[value.encode()]` might fix it, but then it says:

```
AttributeError: 'bytes' object has no attribute 'encode'
```

(Well which is it, TF?  bytes or str?)

The row in the input file contains:

```
ImageID,Source,LabelName,Confidence,XMin,XMax,YMin,YMax,IsOccluded,IsTruncated,IsGroupOf,IsDepiction,IsInside,XClick1X,XClick2X,XClick3X,XClick4X,XClick1Y,XClick2Y,XClick3Y,XClick4Y
000411001ff7dd4f,xclick,/m/09b5t,1,0.1734375,0.46875,0.19791667,0.7916667,0,0,1,0,0
```

The feature map for the TFRecord:

```
feature_map = {
standard_fields.TfExampleFields.object_bbox_ymin:
dataset_util.float_list_feature(
filtered_data_frame_boxes.YMin.to_numpy()),
standard_fields.TfExampleFields.object_bbox_xmin:
dataset_util.float_list_feature(
filtered_data_frame_boxes.XMin.to_numpy()),
standard_fields.TfExampleFields.object_bbox_ymax:
dataset_util.float_list_feature(
filtered_data_frame_boxes.YMax.to_numpy()),
standard_fields.TfExampleFields.object_bbox_xmax:
dataset_util.float_list_feature(
filtered_data_frame_boxes.XMax.to_numpy()),
standard_fields.TfExampleFields.object_class_text:
dataset_util.bytes_list_feature(
filtered_data_frame_boxes.LabelName.to_numpy()),
standard_fields.TfExampleFields.object_class_label:
dataset_util.int64_list_feature(
filtered_data_frame_boxes.LabelName.map(lambda x: label_map[x])
.to_numpy()),
standard_fields.TfExampleFields.filename:
dataset_util.bytes_feature('{}.jpg'.format(image_id)),
standard_fields.TfExampleFields.source_id:
dataset_util.bytes_feature(image_id),
standard_fields.TfExampleFields.image_encoded:
dataset_util.bytes_feature(encoded_image),
}
```

Any idea? I installed with pip3 and had to fix a bunch of package deprecation bugs before it got to this point.

```
pip3 install tensorflow
pip3 install tensorflow-object-detection-api
```

EDITs:

Versions:

```
tensorflow                         2.3.1
tensorflow-object-detection-api    0.1.1
```

I tried

```
  standard_fields.TfExampleFields.filename:
      dataset_util.bytes_feature(bytes(('{}.jpg'.format(image_id)),'ascii')),
```

but it gets the following:

```
TypeError: '000411001ff7dd4f' has type str, but expected one of: bytes
```

(Where did the .jpg go?)

Comment: I am pretty sure that the API is expecting the *contents* of the file, not the name. You might even have to use something else to load the image data into an array representing the bitmap.

Comment: "The row in the input file contains:" What input file are you talking about? That clearly isn't a .jpg.

Comment: At any rate, you should *definitely* not be trying to solve the problem by editing the library code. It's not clear to me which, if any of the code boxes here represent the code *that you wrote*.

Comment: Hi Karl, the field is called "filename".  I am pretty sure it's expecting the file name.

Comment: I'm not accustomed to 3.x code representing file names in bytes, but I guess that's a consequence of the TF interface. :/

Answer (score 3):

The TypeError appears to refer to a filename created in this line:

```py
dataset_util.bytes_feature('{}.jpg'.format(image_id)),
```

Perhaps this image name should be bytes, like so:

```py
dataset_util.bytes_feature('{}.jpg'.format(image_id).encode()),
```

Comment: Thanks, that gives "'bytes' object has no attribute 'format'".  Some kinda operator precedence issue with this b'...' trick.

Comment: Ah... I amended my answer. str.format is only for strings obviously, so it must be converted to bytes after formatting, with str.encode

Answer (score 2):

So ideally, Karl would be right and we "should *definitely* not be trying to solve the problem by editing the library code."

But it would seem my library code isn't working at the moment.  Found a relevant [github issue bug](https://github.com/tensorflow/models/issues/7997).

and fixed it using .encode()  It seems the bytes() solution also worked.  The missing '.jpg' was because it moved onto the next time and died there.

Fixed code:

```
  standard_fields.TfExampleFields.filename:
      dataset_util.bytes_feature(('{}.jpg'.format(image_id)).encode('utf-8')),
  standard_fields.TfExampleFields.source_id:
      dataset_util.bytes_feature(image_id.encode('utf-8')),
```

Just moved onto the next bug.

```
TypeError: '/m/09b5t' has type str, but expected one of: bytes
```

Same error, but for `bytes_list_feature()` call.  Fixed by changing:

```
  standard_fields.TfExampleFields.object_class_text:
      dataset_util.bytes_list_feature(
          filtered_data_frame_boxes.LabelName.to_numpy()),
```

to:

```
  standard_fields.TfExampleFields.object_class_text:
      dataset_util.bytes_list_feature(
          filtered_data_frame_boxes.LabelName.map(lambda x: x.encode('utf8')).to_numpy()()),
```

following a pull request: https://github.com/tensorflow/models/pull/4771/files (and also had to change `as_matrix()` to `to_numpy()`)